# SwiftUI List -> ForEach -> Item is a let, so i can't change a value

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I want to change the value of "clicked" if I tap on an item of the List (just toggle it) ...
But this error comes: "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'item' is a 'let' constant"
I understand it right I think but I don't know how to fix that "item" ins't a let anymore
Even when i create a mutating func in the struct to change the value doesn't work

Thank you for helping!

```
struct Gamemode: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var clicked: Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var gamemodes: [Gamemode] = [
        Gamemode(id: 1, name: "example text", clicked: false),
        Gamemode(id: 2, name: "second example text", clicked: false),
        Gamemode(id: 3, name: "third example text", clicked: false),
        Gamemode(id: 4, name: "fourth example text", clicked: false)
    ]
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(gamemodes) { item in
                    VStack {
                        Text("Selection \(item.id)")
                        Text("\(item.name)")
                    }
                    .background(Color((item.clicked) ? .blue : .yellow))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        item.clicked.toggle()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but perhaps so:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Gamemode: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var clicked: Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var gamemodes: [Gamemode] = [
        Gamemode(id: 1, name: "example text", clicked: false),
        Gamemode(id: 2, name: "second example text", clicked: false),
        Gamemode(id: 3, name: "third example text", clicked: false),
        Gamemode(id: 4, name: "fourth example text", clicked: false)
    ]



    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<gamemodes.count) { index in
                    VStack {
                        Text("Selection \(gamemodes[index].id)")
                        Text("\(gamemodes[index].name)")
                    }
                    .background(Color((gamemodes[index].clicked) ? .blue : .yellow))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        gamemodes[index].clicked.toggle()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```